# Azure SQL Database times out with nothing but a login request

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I just migrated a copy of our production database up to Azure SQL. After finishing the migration, I pointed the connection string of our Test instance to the Azure SQL database, then I tried to run the app.

Because I had changed the web.config, of course, I was not logged out.  So, I tried to log in, and I got a database timeout issue.

I looked at the usage chart in the Azure Portal, and just the task of logging in pegged it to 100%.  So, I upped the DTU allotment from the default of 10 to 100 (which of course made it a lot more expensive) and then tried again.

Same result.

Seriously? How high do I need to set the DTU's so that I can just log in?  I'd be curious to know your experience.  For just the most simple operations, what should I expect to have to set the DTU allotment to?

Comment: Are you sure it's a DTU issue causing the timeout?

Comment: Nope. But it seems logical.  I can connect just fine to the Azure SQL db via SSMS. Run queries, do updates, run sp's. etc.  So the database itself can receive a connection from my localhost and from our Test server.  And I can use the app just fine when pointing at any other database, so it's not the app or the code. But when I point it at the Azure DB, it times out.  And looking at the usage monitor, it also pegs to 100%.

Comment: There's more to it than it seems. You wouldn't need any significant DTU quantity to login - that wouldn't make any sense. Picking the lowest-tier available would provide the same login experience as the highest tier. Are there other operations hitting the database? Is the database being indexed?

Comment: Indexes. The problem is no indexes. So apparently the handy little Data Migration Tool that Microsoft built doesn't get indexes and create them.